# Change default @TransactionAttribute value for all session bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb

How to change default @TransactionAttribute value from REQUIRED to SUPPORT for all session bean in EJB 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/)(see 13.3.7 Specification of the Transaction Attributes for a Bean’s Methods) doesn't provides a way to set a transactional attribute shared by all session beans.

An alternative to annotate every bean is to define the attribute in a ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor file, but this implies to define an xml entry per bean.

e.g.:

```
<method>
    <ejb-name>EJBNAME1</ejb-name>
    <method-name>*</method-name>
</method>
```